# Will division result of 2 numbers with the same ratio always be the same?

Tags: floating-point, binary, division

`a` is an `integer`.
`b` is also an `integer`, but declared as `double`.
`c = a/b`,  and `c` is also declared as `double`.

And, there are `a2`, `b2`, `c2`, with similar rules as `a`, `b`, `c`.
Also, in term of **decimal** algebra, the 2 groups of numbers satisfy: `a / b = a2 / b2`, *(e.g `8 / 18.0 = 12 / 27.0`)*.

**The questions is:**

- In computer (**binary**), will `c` and `c2` always be exactly the same?
  e.g

  ```
  111 / 135.0 = 0.8222222222222222
  333 / 405.0 = 0.8222222222222222
  ```

*(My guess is yes, since all integers are able to be represented in binary with limited digit, but not totally sure will that be different when it comes to division in computer.)*

---

### @Update

Assume the computer / language use 32 bits for integer, and 64 bits for double.

(BTW, this question hits when writing a test case, not sure simply using `==` will be enough, or a small delta (`= (expected - actual) / actual`) is allowed, e.g `+/- 0.000001`).

Comment: If you have, say, 64 bit ints and 64 bit doubles then I think this will break down when you exceed the no of mantissa bits in the double (53).

Comment: @PaulR Assume this is in `Java`, where integers are 32 bits, and doubles are 64 bits, will the answer be yes then?

Comment: Yes, with that constraint I suspect you’re OK, but I can’t prove it easily. You need someone like @EricPostpischil for a guru-level answer.

Comment: Where you mention "decimal" algebra, did you mean "rational number"? Neither 8/18 nor 12/27 can be represented exactly as a finite decimal fraction. They are equal in rational number arithmetic.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, I mean `rational number`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

Yes, if:

- `a` and `a2` are 32-bit integers,
- `b` and `b2` are non-zero Java `double` values, and
- `a` / `b` = `a2` / `b2`,

then `a / b` equals `a2 / b2`. (Note that `a` / `b` denotes arithmetic on real numbers, while `a / b` denotes floating-point arithmetic. `4` / `3` is exactly 1⅓, while `4./3` is 1.3333333333333332593184650249895639717578887939453125.)

### Proof

Per a comment from the author, this is for Java, which uses IEEE 754, including IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point for `double`.

A basic property of most floating-point operations is that the computed result is the real number result rounded to the nearest value representable in the floating-point format. A consequence of this is:

- If two operations have the same real number result and use the same rounding rule, they have the same floating-point result.

(There are various rounding rules. Java uses round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, meaning that the nearest representable value is used, and, if there is a tie, the candidate with the even low bit is used.)

Another consequence is:

- If the real number result of an operation is representable in the floating-point format, it is the floating-point result. (There is no rounding error.)

Now let’s consider the expressions `a / b` and `a2 / b2`. Due to the mixed types, the first step in each is to convert `a` or `a2`, respectively, from its integer type to `double`. The question tells us to assume the integer type has 32 bits. All 32-bit integers are exactly representable in `double` (because `double` has 53-bit significands). The mathematical result of converting a value is of course the value itself, since a conversion is intended to change the type, not the value. Therefore, the result of converting `a` or `a2` to `double` is exactly `a` or `a2`, respectively.

Next, there is the division, `a / b` or `a2 / b2`. We are told that `a` / `b` = `a2` / `b2`. This tells us that the real number result of `a / b` equals the real number result of `a2 / b2`. Since these two operations have the same real number result and use the same rounding rule, their floating-point results are the same.

### Discussion

Some limits of the above are:

- If `a` or `a2` may exceed 53 bits, it may have a value not representable in `double`. Then the operation of converting it to `double` will have to round it. Rounding may affect `a` and `a2` differently, and then the quotients `a / b` and `a2 / b2` may differ.
- Some programming languages are not strict about how floating-point operations are performed, and they do not conform to IEEE-754 rules. I believe the above holds for Java, but there could be issues in C or C++.

Note that `b` and `b2` could be so small (including zero) that the quotient overflows, and the computed result is infinity. Nonetheless, the fact that `a` / `b` = `a2` / `b2` would require that both results are infinity or neither is—the rule that the floating-point results of equal real number results are equal still holds.

If `a`, `a2`, `b`, and `b2` are zeros, then both operations will produce a NaN, but two NaNs will not compare as equal.

If `a` and `a2` are not zero but `b` and `b2` are, then both operations will produce infinities. The sign will be the XOR of the signs of the numerator and the divisor. This means that `a / b` and `a2 / b2` could produce different infinities (one positive, one negative) even if `a` = `a2` and `b` = `b2`, because IEEE-754 has both +0 and −0, which compare equal but have different signs.

Comment: I prefer "real number operation" rather than "mathematical operation". When studying abstract algebra as a mathematics student, I met a lot of different, equally mathematical, structures that define division differently. Arguably, IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point arithmetic is mathematical. It is defined and one can apply mathematical reasoning to it. The real numbers are a specific set with operations defined on the set members.